# Try to find unique numbers in a long list, and return them in order. (prev. version did not work)

Tags: python, list, unique

You may consider this question is prev. answered, but the last version doesn't work with 2 digits number
Given a list of numbers, find and print the elements that appear in it only once. Such elements should be printed in the order in which they occur in the original list.

so here's my code (being fixed by other pythoneers)

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
sortedLst = sorted(a)
unique = []
uniqueOrd = []

for i in range(len(a) - 2):
     if sortedLst[i + 1] != sortedLst[i] and sortedLst[i + 1] != sortedLst[i + 2]:
            unique.append(sortedLst[i + 1])

for num in a:
    if num in unique:
        uniqueOrd.append(num)

print(*uniqueOrd)
```

but the output does not work with 2 digits number, how can I fix this bug?

Comment: Do you want a more `Pythonic` approach instead?  Or try to learn to debug your code in a visaul platform - https://pythontutor.com ?

Comment: pythonic approach please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to labor yourself on finding the `uniques` from a long list, just consider the nice lib from `collections` - Counter. It's faster and more Pythonic.

```
A = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
sortedLst = sorted(A)         # this is just to confirm your inputs..

from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(A)
print(counts)

uniques = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == 1] # just check the frequency (v) 

print(uniques)
```

Try some inputs like:  2 3 1 4 22 33 44 55 33 22

```
[2, 3, 1, 4, 44, 55]
```